# Microsoft Edge Chromium and an App-V'ed plugin

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, appv, microsoft-edge-chromium

I'm experiencing the combination of a locally installed Microsoft Edge Chromium Enterprise Edition and Microsoft App-V. I try to App-V a browser plugin for a locally installed Microsoft Edge Chrome Enterprise.

I have an App-V bubble and Internet Explorer is started with this bubble in the background using the `/appvve` command-line option.

My first suggestion was: 
Replace the file path to iexplore.exe to the new file path of msedge.exe, eg. 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --site-per-process -url https://www.website.com /appvve:[App-V PackageID]_[App-V PackageVersionID]`

This works *only* when MS Edge has no running instances already.
The `--site-per-process` option should help isolate the process of Edge Chromium.

When Microsoft Edge is already opened, there is some magic: the bubble is active for some seconds and after that the App-V bubble is closed.

ProcessExplorer of SysInternals does a great work: it tells me a secondary process of Edge Chromium is started with the bubble on the background.  
Then the subprocesses of the secundary started instance are brought to the primaraly started instance and when this all is done, the secondary started instance - including the App-V bubble - is closed. 
The webpage is opened, but the connection to the App-V bubble is lost.

The same happens when MS Edge-with-app-v is running bubble-a and you want start a secondary instance with bubble-b.


Could anyone tell me how to tell MS Edge to *really* isolate its processes and how it could work with multiple loaded App-V bubbles?

Comment: The issue looks complex and needs deep investigation to find the cause and possible solution/ workaround. I suggest you create an MS support ticket by visiting [this link](https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/onboarding). Please note that this is paid support service. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have successfully got around this is with the --no-sandbox, --app, and --user-data-dir switches.

For example:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-sandbox --user-data-dir"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge\AppV --app="https://www.website.com" /appvve:[App-V PackageID]_[App-V PackageVersionID]

This opens up the page in an App window and uses its own directory so the process isn't merged with existing or new instances of Edge that launch in the default directory.

I found this kept crashing until --no-sandbox was introduced.  however, I'm a little on edge as the Sandbox helps keeps this secure.  I'm also wondering how the Sandbox is interfering with App-V.

This is a workaround, but I do think MS will need to investigate this further as clearly the --site-per-process isn't separating each tab, at least not how we would expect.

Comment: Thanks for your helpfull reply. This is doing the trick!

I made an equivalent of the next cmd file:
``Set RandomFolder=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge\%RANDOM%%RANDOM%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-sandbox --user-data-dir="%RandomFolder%" --app="https://www.website.com" /appvve:[App-V PackageID]_[App-V PackageVersionID]``

and at close of the application instance:
``rd /s /q "%RandomFolder%"``

Comment: If you use Ivanti Workspace Control, the command line arguments could be: `--no-sandbox --user-data-dir="%TEMP%\Edge\%PFAPPID%" --app="https://www.website.com" /appvve:[App-V PackageID]_[App-V PackageVersionID]`

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tried to virtualize this under App-V, I am aware that others have done so, for example NickIT.

Off hand, I would guess that RunVirtual is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

NickIT is doing the opposite of my trial: He creates an App-V of Microsoft Edge Chromium. 
I try to load more than one App-Ved application from the locally, physically installed browser.
RunVirtual could be an option with single virtualized application. It is not an option when you have more than one virtualized application which should run from the browser. RunVirtual has some big disadvantages why I do not use it.